# How do you do file i/o in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I try to do

```
(define o (open-output-file "txt.txt"))

(write "hope" o)

(close-output-port o)
```

It works the first time, then it says

```
open-output-file: file exists
  path: C:\...\proj3\txt.txt
```

and refuses to it write anymore to it.  I checked permissions and it's not that.
I even sshed into my schools system and it gives an "unspecified return value" error
when I try to open the file a second time.

Any help would likely add years to my life, this is getting aggravating.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Scheme, from at least R5RS, defines `call-with-{input,output}-file` and `with-{input,output}-from-file`.  These ensure that the created ports are properly closed for non-local exits and are properly opened (kept open) when a continuation is retained.

As for your file existing, there is less standardization.  In R5RS the behavior when opening a file for output when the file exists is 'unspecified' and there is no standard function of `delete-file` nor even `file-exists?`.  Most R5RS Schemes offer a non-standard way to delete a file.  In R7RS you can find these two functions.

[EDIT reason="Removed code in response to first comment"]

Comment: BAD BAD BAD! Just call `delete-file`, it will not error if the file does not exist. In any language that pattern is a classic race condition. :)